# Returning nothing instead of NaN

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a simple app that calculates BMI and I'm struggling with one small problem. I have 2 edit text fields, which are allowed to type numbers only. The point is when one of the text fields are empty the app is to generate a toast message and display nothing. I wrote an if statement to check if an edit text is empty and if not just to calculate further.
All would work fine, but I needed to put return statement and Android Studio suggested me writing "return 0;" so did I.
This is the code responsible for calculations:

```
/// parse input value from edittext field into double type
private double weight() {
    EditText weightInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weight_input);
    String sWeightInput = weightInput.getEditableText().toString();
    if (sWeightInput.matches("")){
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.noweight, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        String weight = sWeightInput;
        double weightTyped = Double.parseDouble(weight);
        return  weightTyped;
    }
     return 0;
}

private double heigh() {
    EditText heightInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.height_input);
    String sHightInput = heightInput.getEditableText().toString();
    if (sHightInput.matches("")){
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.noheight, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        String height = sHightInput;
        double heightTyped = Double.parseDouble(height);
        heightTyped = heightTyped / 100;
        heightTyped = heightTyped * heightTyped;
        return heightTyped;
    }
    return 0;
}

//make calculations and return the output value
public void makeCalculations(View view){
    double result = weight() / heigh();
    String message = String.valueOf(result);
    TextView bmiSummaryTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bmi_calculation);
    bmiSummaryTextView.setText(message);
}
```

[This is the interface of the app.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ELId.png)

To sum up, all I want to do is to display nothing instead of NaN (not a number).

Comment: in `makeCalculations` check if either weight or heigh is zero before doing the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Return a non-primitive `Double` rather than a `double`, and you will be able to use `null` as a value. Be sure to check for this value though, or you'll run into a `NullPointerException`.

Alternatively, you could look into using optionals, but since you're using Android you might need an external library for that (unless your minimum SDK version is high enough, then you can use Java 8's Optional).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably if in your calculation `weight() / height` height is 0 it outputs NaN because it is infinity.

Also put your `return 0;` after `Toast.makeText()` in the condition. AS grumbles because you are not returning a value in the `if` branch.

```
if (sHightInput.matches("")){
    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.noheight, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return 0;
}
```

Maybe this will help you also to avoid dividing by zero.

```
public void makeCalculations(View view) {
    String message = "Invalid input!";
    if (weight() > 0 && height() > 0) {
        double result = weight() / heigh();
        String message = String.valueOf(result);
    }
    TextView bmiSummaryTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bmi_calculation);
    bmiSummaryTextView.setText(message);
}
```

Comment: The code you have provided doesn't work at all, it works after putting
TextView bmiSummaryTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bmi_calculation);
    bmiSummaryTextView.setText(message)
into brace from if statement. Thanks anyway, now it works !